# typescript get all existing keys as pass them as to a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the a constant and I would like to infer all its keys in a function within in:

```
const objectArgs = {
   a: 1,
   b: () => "str",

   // I DO NOT WANT TO USE any or `this.a` since I want IDE autocompletion and
   // within my code actually all keys are further processed by another class
   // and it's actual value is not 1 but let's say it `my-key-1`
   // I would prefere to use an args which would contain all keys of current object
   testFn(args: TransformedResult<???>) {
      return args.a;
   }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You haven't quite explained what `TransformedResult` is clearly enough, so you might want to either remove it or define it to make this a [mre].  Still, would something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMRJVW) work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate failed use cases.

Comment: Your result works only with TS 4.4.4, not with 4.3.5 where I'm getting an error "TS2304 : Cannot find name this". Any other ideas ?

Comment: I've just tried to update to TS 4.4.4, and even in there I get another error "'this' is undefined" so for sure it must be a problem within my tsconfig

Comment: `typeof this` has only been supported starting with TS4.4+, I think, as implemented in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43898.  If you're still getting an error though then it would be helpful if you could reproduce it in a shareable web IDE like the TypeScript Playground.  Otherwise I don't know that we can make much progress here.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you unless you provide a [mre] that I can look at in my IDE, or provide a link to an existing web IDE project that demonstrates what you're seeing.  I gather that you are having continuing issues, but right now all I can do is offer sympathy.

Comment: Comments are not great places to put code blocks; you can [edit] your question, and/or you can put something in the TypeScript playground and provide a https://tsplay.dev link.

Comment: Apparently there are still problems with `typeof this` if I move this in an interface, I lose the autocomplete feature of TS while typing `arg.`.
Sample [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2KRrN)

Comment: If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) that `objectArgsT0` is a `T0` then you are telling the compiler to treat it as such, and that type has an index signature, so the compiler has no idea what keys are on it anymore.  I don't think `objectArgs` is assignable to `T0` anyway, because contravariance of function parameters means `testFn` cannot assume that its argument isn't some other subtype of `T0`.  This is no longer the same topic as the original question;l you might want to [edit] the question or open a new one.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your support @jcalz, I've posted it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790457/ts-autocomplete-for-interface-type-with-index-signature-not-known-in-advance)